# FORCE IDE : right click not working on Project Explorer

Tags: java

I am using FORCE IDE for the first time. I could install it and have event created a Force.com Project by fetching the metadata from salesforce.

I am using the 29.0 FORCE IDE plugin and using Developer Edition.

and my issue is : I am unable to see any options(Import Export Force.com) been shown on right clicking src folder in Project Explorer window.

I am sorry this is quite a basic question, and have tried to reinstall and create new project.But its not helping.

What would be the reason?

Comment: When you right click on the project name, do you have the 'Force.com' submenu? If yes, what options are listed there?

Comment: @jibennett : my problem is i am not getting any option at all on right clicking on project name.  Though the plugin has worked in fetching all the metadata from salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Window->Reset Perspective this should reset all the default options including the right-click menus.

Comment: @jibennett530 Got to know this option as well.THanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Tried upgrading my Eclipse by using option : Help > Check Updates.
and later individually upgrading the project to latest version of salesforce. This fixed the issue